# Issue with addAuthStateDidChangeListener being called twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase and per their docs, I'm checking to see whether or not a user's logged in state changes. The problem resides in the listener block, where the code is being called twice when the apps launched (user's logged in). It's not too much of a deal, but Firebase is creating two values in connections and removing both. How would I fix this issue? I'd need to call it after the user is obtained in the listener though and not outside because there is no guarantee that user will exist outside that block if it's not finished getting the user data first.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let theUser = user {
            // User is signed in.

            // CODE IN HERE IS CALLED TWICE UPON APP LAUNCH (WHEN USERS LOGGED IN).... WHY?
            self.currentUser = theUser
            print("LOGGED IN!!!!")


            self.updateUsersStatus(user: self.currentUser)

        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOG_IN, sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: usually this happens because you don't remove the addAuthStateDidChangeListener when you finish using it but you keep launching it ( for example every time a view controller is created or appeared you start the auth event, but you don't remove it when  the view disappears)

Comment: check  this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth#method-detail   and be sure to remove the FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle to avoid double calls

Comment: in which function are you calling this method ?

Comment: All of that is called in viewDidLoad. From my understanding the listener stopped listening after another view in my TabBarController is clicked, but from what you're saying that's incorrect and that I should manually unregister this in viewDidDisappear ?

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is called twice when all of that is in viewDidLoad for one view controller.

Comment: Figured it out, I should have been using         if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
 since user was already logged in rather than using listener.

Comment: @Jamie22       I am facing the same problem as you did, how did you fix it eventually, are you using removeAuthEventObserverWithHandle? Can you post your code? Thanks

Comment: From firebase DOC - Note: currentUser might also be nil because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use a listener to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case. @Jamie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click or <kbd>option</kbd> + click on the `addAuthStateDidChangeListener` function. You will see the following:

```
Registers a block as an "auth state did change" listener. To be invoked when:
    - The block is registered as a listener,
    - The current user changes, or,
    - The current user's access token changes.
```

To summarize - the block get's called immediately and then most likely gets called again after verifying the FIRApp and/or FIRAuth objects do not contain any stale data. So the behavior of invoking the callback twice should be expected and managed appropriately.

Comment: I'd like to do this, but am not sure how to check for these events within the completion closure. I would think there is some state property for the auth parameter, but I can't find anything like that. How would I perform these checks against each of these events?

Comment: check that the user parameter being passed into the block is not nil. If it's not nil then you have an authenticated user. And to check outside the context of the block for an authenticated user: `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issues as reported by Jamie22. Strange thing - I got two similar app setups, but only one app calls the auth state listener method twice on change.

This workaround is what solved the issue for me:

```
var activeUser:FIRUser!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth:FIRAuth, user:FIRUser?) in
        if let user = user {
            if(self.activeUser != user){
                self.activeUser = user
                print("-> LOGGED IN AS \(user.email)")
            }
        } else {
            print("-> NOT LOGGED IN")
        }
    })
}
```

By checking if the appUser has changed on auth state change, you can get rid of the second call, because it will be equal to the user you get in the first call.